# Principal Component Analysis definition

Tags: transform, pca

I have just learned about this method, so I am not very familiar with it. As far as I know, Principal Component Anlysis (aka PCA) is used to transform a vector $x$ that belongs to a space of $d$ dimensions to a vector $y$ that belongs to a space of $p$ diamensions, where $p\ll d$ . The new vector $y$ consists of p uncorrelated components. I also know that these $p$ components hold the maximum possible energy of the initial vector $x$ . Last but not least, since PCA is an orthogonal transformation, it should minimize the error norm (the difference between the initial vector and its projection). Correct me if I am wrong.

So let's say we have a random vector $x$ that belong to space $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and we use PCA to project it to a new space of $p$ dimensions where $p\ll d$. I have come up with three statements. However, I can't find out which one is the correct one:

1. PCA projects vector $x$ to a space of $p$ dimensions where the projection has minimum energy
2. PCA projects vector $x$ to a space of $p$ dimensions where the difference between the initial vector and the projection has maximum energy.
3. PCA projects vector $x$ to a space which is  homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}^{p}$

So which is the correct statement?

Comment: excellent question.  i'll be listening in to any answers.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks!Do you have any suggestions or thoughts about the correct answer?

Comment: no.  i've seen a couple of articles on PCA, but i dunno what it's about.

Comment: Sounds like a quizz for some homework. Is this the case? What is a space which is "uniform with"? What is you educated guess so far?

Comment: Do you have to select one out of the 3 options OR did you create these statements? none seems totally correct to me. If you need a good definition, I can provide this.

Comment: @serafeim To be more precise I didn't make up these statements...They are part of a multiple choice question. So, only one of them is correct and that is certain. I edited my question since I hadn't use the right terminology. So check them again and let me know what you think

Comment: @LaurentDuval I edited my question...I meant **homeomorphic space**...Didn't translate the term properly...Do you know which is the correct statement?

Comment: Some of us here love to answer, to help the person who has thought about the question, and is not sure. We don't know yet what you would say, and why, and why you are unsure

Comment: Clearly, some terms are not clear to me. I don't know what an "error norm" could be, and homeomorphism requires a topology, which thus is not clear to me so far

Comment: @LaurentDuval As I have told I am not very familiar with this method...I just learned about it and trying to figure this out.I wrote down everything I was educated. If u check, before some edits to this question, I had written my guess as well which was the second statement since I thought it was closest to the fact that I want my p components to contain the maximum possible energy. However, after that, I considered that we need to minimize the error norm,which I think comes in contrast with the second option.The error is the difference between my initial random vector and its projection.

Comment: @LaurentDuval So is any of them at least wrong for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By projecting a vector x using PCA (on the PCs), you maximize the variance in the reduced space. Initially, the space is not optimal in terms of maximizing the variance.

So:

> PCA projects vector  to a space of  dimensions where the
>   difference between the initial vector and the projection has maximum
>   energy.

(initially the is no maximum variance but after projection the space is optimal in terms of maximizing the variance in the PC defined space)

PS:

Minimizing J1 (the error) corresponds to maximizing the quadratic form e'Se. After demeaning this is e'X'Xe. Set now w = Xe (the projection of the data X). The variance in the projected space is w'w that is equal to the e'X'Xe. Thus, minimizing the error means maximizing varinace

Comment: Doesn't that contrast the fact that since PCA is an orthogonal transformation, it should minimize the error norm? I mean isn't the error norm the difference between the initial vector and the projection?

Comment: yes, but maximum energy means minimum error in terms of projection. I wouldn't really choose any of the 3 cause it's not clear but since you have to select, 2 makes more sense to me

Comment: Hmm so the fact the we demand maximum energy of this vector concludes that we minimize the error as well?

Comment: yes you project onto a space that has maximum variance by reducing the projection error as much as possible

Comment: So the first statement would be correct if it was something like that: **PCA projects vector x to a space of p dimensions where the projection has maximum energy** ??

Comment: I am just still a bit confused since the **difference between the initial vector and the projection** is considered to be the error vector...Isn't the energy equal to the norm of this vector? If yes, if we maximize it then we maximize the error as well...So we don't get minimum error but maximum..What am I missing here?

Comment: Follow this track :)

Comment: @LaurentDuval What about my last comment? Doesn't this answer mean we maximize the error norm?

Comment: Minimizing J1 (the error) corresponds to maximizing the quadratic form e'Se. After demeaning this is e'X'Xe. Set now w = Xe (the projection of the data X). The variance in the projected space is w'w that is equal to the e'X'Xe. Thus, minimizing the error means maximizing varinace